# Display Data in form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have `Clients` table with `Client_Name` , `Client_Address` and `Client_Phone` columns.

And I have a form `Client Manager` to EDIT/DELETE the clients.

How can I display the Clients table in the form and enable user to manage (EDIT/DELETE) it ?

I know one way to do this is [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) But it doesn't fulfill my needs.

I want something like this :
[image: table]

I have done this before in php/mysql , like this :

```
   <table>
   <tr><td>Client Name</td><td>Client Address</td><td>Client  Phone</td><td> EDIT </td><td> DELETE</td></tr>
<?php
foreach ($clients->result_array() as $key)
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$key['Client_Name']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$key['Client_Address']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$key['Client_Phone']."</td>";
 echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$key['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
 echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id".$key['id']."'>Delete</a></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
```

How to do something like this in c# ?

Comment: extend DataGridView to your own needs then.

Comment: To me, buttons in a grid like that are just clutter.  Use a BindingNavigator with edit and delete buttons used against selected row(s).

Comment: It could be that you are just unfamiliar with the DataGridView. It has excellent support for CRUD. It is not always the best user experience, but look at this [example](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/). It is VB.Net but should be easy enough to follow.

Comment: If DataGridView won't do, I agree with @DonBoitnott, use a Binding Navigator.

Answer (score 1):

In windows Forms you can use:

- DataGridView for show data in a grid.
- ToolStrip as a command bar above grid

**Editable**

---

Using Toolstrip for add, delete and save operations. Edit will be done in grid.

- Add Button: adds a new record at the end of grid.
- Delete Button: removes selected record from grid.
- Save Button: saves changes including add, edit and deletes.

[image]

**Non-Editable**

---

Using Toolstrip for add, delete and edit operations. add and edit usually will be done in separate form, delete will be done using after a MessageBox for confirm delete.

- Add Button: Shows a Form and you create new entity in that form and Save it in database and then after closing that form, you reload data to your grid.
- Delete Button: Shows a MessageBox to confirm deletion and after you clicked on yes/ok and MessageBox closed, you delete data and reload data to grid.
- Edit Button: Pass data to a Form and shows the form and you edit you edit entity in that form and Save it in database, and then after closing that form you reload data to your grid.
- There is no need to Save Button.

[image]

Screen shot of Add Form, Edit Form is like Add Form and show entity data in controls:

[image]